# How to use PHP to connect to sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I want to use PHP to connect to sql server database.

I installed xampp 1.7.0(php 5.2) and SQLSRV20.  I've added the extensions in `php.ini` and I get this error:

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to 
server: 10.85.80.229 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php on line 07
```

Code:

```
<?php
$myServer = "10.85.80.229";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "testdb";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
?>
```

What does this error message mean and how do I connect to SQL Server?

Comment: try $myServer = "localhost";

Comment: Are you sure that the mysql server is actually running?

Comment: i want to connect to mssql ie sql server. i have xampp(mysql,apache) running

Answer (score 13):

enable mssql in php.ini

`;extension=php_mssql.dll`

to

`extension=php_mssql.dll`

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php  
$serverName = "ServerName"; 
$uid = "sqlusername";   
$pwd = "sqlpassword";  
$databaseName = "DBName"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                         "Database"=>$databaseName); 

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

$tsql = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM tblContact";  

/* Execute the query. */  

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

if ( $stmt )  
{  
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";  
}   
else   
{  
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.*/  

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  
{  
     echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";  
     echo "Col2: ".$row[1]."\n";  
     echo "Col3: ".$row[2]."<br>\n";  
     echo "-----------------<br>\n";  
}  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */  
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

http://robsphp.blogspot.ae/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html

Answer (score 3):

if your using  sqlsrv_connect you have to download and install MS sql driver for your php. download it here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
extract it to your php folder or ext in xampp folder
then add this on the end of the line in your php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

im using xampp version 5.5 so its name  php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll &  php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

if you are using xampp version 5.5  dll files is not included in the link...hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test.php on line 4

Answer (score 2):

```
 $server_name = "your server name";
 $database_name = "your database name";
 try
  {
   $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server_name;Database=$database_name;ConnectionPooling=0", "user_name", "password");
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{

    $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: how about not using PDO?

Comment: By only using PDO you can connect php with sql server. Otherwise you have to use mysql.

Comment: Thanks hassan. I tried this http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php and it worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localhost` instead of your IP address.

e.g,

```
$myServer = "localhost";
```

And also double check your mysql username and password.

Comment: i have tried with localhost aswell, also by adding port. but to no fruit

Answer (score 1):

for further investigation: print out the mssql error message:

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Could not connect to database: ".mssql_get_last_message());
```

It is also important to specify the port: On MS SQL Server 2000, separate it with a comma:

```
$myServer = "10.85.80.229:1443";
```

or

```
$myServer = "10.85.80.229,1443";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

1. first download below software
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 - need to install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 - when you run this software . it will extract dll file.
and paste two dll file(php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll,extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll) this location C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.40\ext\ (pls make sure your current version)

2)edit php.ini file
add below line
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Please refer screenshort
 [add dll in your php.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWOeL.png)

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL connect  to php

1. Install the drive from [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
2. After install, you will get some files. Store it in your system temp folder
3. Check your php version, thread or non thread, and window bit - 32 or 64
   (Thread or non thread, this is get you by phpinfo())
4. According to your system & xampp configration (php version and all) copy 2 files (php_sqlsrv & php_pdo_sqlsrv) to xampp/php/ext folder .
5. Add to php.ini file :

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
```

(php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll  are the files which you copied in 4th step)

6. Next here is the Php Code to connect to database :

   ```php
   $serverName ="DESKTOP-me\\MSSQLSERVER01"; (servername\\instanceName)


   // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
   // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.

   $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"testdb","CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");

   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
        //echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }

   //$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.master ('name') VALUES ('test')";
   $sql = "SELECT *  FROM dbo.master";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
         echo $row['id'].", ".$row['name']."<br />";
   }

   sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [matrix](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16) to understand the compatibility of different versions of Windows/SQL Server/PHP drivers.

- Download PHP driver dll -
  https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/
- Copy the dll files to
  /ext folder.
- Edit php.ini and add dll names under Dynamic
  Extensions.
- Restart the webserver -Apache or IIS

Eg: using 8.1 version with SQL Server 2019.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts
```

Database Connection test Code - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me, how do I install this driver in live server?

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to connect to database(MSSQL) using Windows Auth, **mssql_connect**' was removed in the 7.0 PHP version. So you can use this instead;

```
$serverName="serverName";
$uid = '';
$pwd = "";
$dbase = "nameOfDB";

$conninfro = array("Database"=>$dbase, "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd);

$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $conninfro);
if( $con === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me, how do I install this driver in live server?

Answer (score 0):

For the following code you have to enable mssql in the php.ini as described at this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

```
$myServer = "10.85.80.229";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "testdb";

$conn = mssql_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass);
if (!$conn)
{ 
  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem (well I hope the same).  Anyways it turned out to be my version of ntwdblib.dll, which was out of date in my PHP folder.

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server_2/Finding_ntwdblib_dll_Version_2000_80_194_0.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$serverName="ServerName";
$uid = 'sa';
$pwd = "password";
$dbase = "dbname";

$conninfro = array("Database"=>$dbase, "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd);

$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $conninfro);
if( $con === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PDO.

1-you must use php_pdo_sqlsrv_xx_nts.dll and php_sqlsrv_xx_nts.dll extensions.

note that you must use the proper version of those for your PHP.

2- use this code

```
    $servername = "IP";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $db='';


try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername;Database=$db", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and then use this code:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("select * from table");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchall();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this to be able to catch the thrown exception:

```
$server_name = "your server name";
$database_name = "your database name";
try {
   $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server_name;Database=$database_name;ConnectionPooling=0", "user_name", "password");
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense