# Connecting to SQL server 2012 on a physical server running Windows server 2012 using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I was wondering how to connect to SQL server 2012 that is on a physical server running Windows server 2012 using PHP.

I have WAMP installed on my pc and we are all connected to a domain. The easy way would probably be to install WAMP/XAMPP on the server but that is not an option. Am I over thinking this or maybe a little bit on the slow side ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PHP to connect to sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632607/how-to-use-php-to-connect-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mssql` extension for PHP to import the MS SQL Server functions ( http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php ) and use them in a similar fashion to how you'd use MySQL.

If you're running SQL Server Express and it's running on a remote computer then you'll need to enable TCP/IP networking as this is disabled by default. Look for the SQL Server Configuration Manager in your Start Menu programs list.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try and let you know.