# How to link up a database in a HTML base website in offline server (Xamp)?

Tags: php, html, sql, xampp

I have created a website for my versity project...But I am asked to add a database in it..That's why I need to know how to add a database via xamp in a website.

Comment: The question is either unclear or too broad. There are plenty tutorials out there teaching how to connect PHP to a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PHP to connect to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632607/how-to-use-php-to-connect-to-sql-server)

Comment: @IronyStack XAMP is not SQL Server. Please, hover over the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create a connection to your database from php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password ="db-password";
$dbname = "db-name";

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
//check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed" .$conn->$connect_error);
}

?>
```

use this link to understand how to create and execute queries.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp