# How to connect QNAP Web server to Microsoft MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, qnap

I'm trying to configure my QNAP TS-231P Web server to connect to a MS SQL database installed on a Windows server (MSSQL Express 2014).

In QNAP Control Panel -> Server Web, I added in the php.ini file this line

```
extension = mssql.so
```

and now running phpinfo() I see the mssql section (Library version is FreeTDS).

My web application, built on CodeIgniter 3.1.9, is unable to connect to MSSQL (it works on XAMPP ver 3.2.2 installed on Windows), I also tried this simple php code:

```
<?php
$connection = mssql_connect('10.10.10.100\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'mypassword');
if (!$connection) {
  die('Unable to connect!');
}
if (!mssql_select_db('MY_DATABASE', $connection)) {
  die('Unable to select database!');
}
$result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE');
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
mssql_free_result($result);
?>
```

but the connection fails.
The question is what can I do for getting a successful connection ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `sa` account for your Web Service. I (**very**) strongly suggest you create a login and user with only the permissions your website needs, and connect using that account. Having a website with full `sysadmin` privileges is a terrible idea.

Comment: You're right, but I'm using sysadmin privileges just in production, first of all I need to get a functioning connection.

Comment: MS SQL Server have to have enabled remote connections. Have you set it? How? See: [Configure the remote access Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php):

> *mssql_connect*
>
> **Warning**
>
> This function was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Rather than it, you should use [sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php):

To be able to connect to MS SQL Server, that server have to accept remote connections. See: [Configure the remote access Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

When you use IP, you have to provide a port number on which MS SQL Server is listening remote connections.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

More about connection to MS SQL Server in this thread: [How to use PHP to connect to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632607/how-to-use-php-to-connect-to-sql-server)

Good luck!